# Webcam not recognized on my Sony Vaio VGN-CR363 laptop

Tags: drivers, hardware, webcam, sony, cheese

when I open Cheese it says No device found.

and i've also tried changing the gstreamer properties

my lsusb http://pastebin.com/BX6B4Wpe

my lspci http://pastebin.com/FZmseTST

i've also tried ricoh drivers..but i'm not sure whether i installed them correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions in this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~r5u87x-loader/+archive/ppa

It should work with your webcam.

Comment: @NateW error : sudo /usr/share/r5u87x/r5u87x-download-firmware.sh
                cd: 78: can't cd to r5u87x

Comment: It works for me. Make sure you have installed r5u87x (sudo apt-get install r5u87x). Then try running the script again

Comment: @natew its the same error again : amithsvati@amith-CR363:~$ sudo /usr/share/r5u87x/r5u87x-download-firmware.sh
This script is going to download and install firmware for Ricoh R5U87x
series cameras. The copyright and license status of this firmware are
unclear.
Do you want to proceed? [y/n] y
Downloading firmware...
cd: 78: can't cd to r5u87x

Comment: Run this in terminal: cd;wget http://www.natewiebe.com/r5u87x-download-firmware.sh;sudo mv ~/r5u87x-download-firmware.sh /usr/share/r5u87x/r5u87x-download-firmware.sh;sudo /usr/share/r5u87x/r5u87x-download-firmware.sh

Comment: Copy that entire block after "Run this in termainal: " and that should work. The script was wrong, so I fixed it. The error was on line 79.

Comment: @NateW : I went to the folder and changed permission to execute as program...now it worked!!! thanks a zillion!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

When I installed cheese on my bodhi 2.4 on my sony vaio vgn-cr353.  Cheese said 'no device found'. I ran the following commands in the terminal:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:r5u87x-loader/ppa`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install r5u87x`
4. `sudo /usr/share/r5u87x/r5u87x-download-firmware.sh`

Cheese started working after that.  Hope this helps someone.